# Show the rank of A equals to the number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

A is an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. How to show that the rank of A equals to the number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A^TA$

Comment: I didn't find a direct duplicate, but note the Answer to [Rank of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583162/rank-of-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-matrix), whose counterexamples illustrate the importance of assuming *real entries* to equality of rank and number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what information you have available.

- If you have the singular value decomposition $A=VDU$, with $V,U$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal, you have $$ A^TA=U^TDV^TVDU=U^TD^2U,$$ and since conjugation with an orthogonal preserves eigenvalues, the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are precisely the squares of the diagonal entries of $D$. As $D$ is diagonal, its rank  is equal to the number of nonzero diagonal entries. And since $U,V$ are invertible, the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of $D$.
- If you have the rank-nullity theorem, you can prove that $\ker A=\ker A^TA$, and so $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same rank. As $A^TA$ is symmetric, it is orthogonally diagonalizable (equivalently, it admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, cfr. the spectral theorem) and so its rank agrees with the number of nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Hi Martin, I haven't learnt VDU decomposition yet. I understand that A^TA has the same rank as A because it's a linear combination of A. Could you explain more about why its rank agrees to the number of non-zero eigenvalues? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is a linear combination of $A$". Because $A^TA$ is symmetric, it is not hard to show that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues will be perpendicular to each other; and, even more, the orthogonal subspace to an eigenvector is invariant. That allows you to construct an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. And then the dimension of the range of $A^TA$ will be precisely the number of elements of that basis that correspond to nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ATA and A have the same nullity and n, so they have the same rank. Thank you for very good explanation on the last question. I wonder if this equality of rank and no. of non-zero eigenvectors still holds for a non-symmetric matrix A.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Easiest example is $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, with both eigenvalues equal to zero, and rank one.